# get the selected value from the dropdown in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i'm working with the laravel and html here. anyhow by doing this i got the data from controller to view and showed that in the dropdown. now the next part is to make crud operation for that. so whenever i select the option from the dropdown the particular ID element should be display.
this is my view code:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label>Name</label>
      <select name="id" class="form-control">
          @foreach($clients as $client)
          <option value="{{ $client->Cid }}" {{ $selectedclients == $client->Cid ? selected="selected" : '' }}>{{ $client->name }}</option> 
      @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and this is my controller:

```
 $Clients = Client::all();
    $selectedClients = Client::first()->Cid;
```

When I run this I'm getting this error:
syntax error, unexpected '=' (View: /home/prasanna/Billing-master/resources/views/Qtcreate.blade.php).

please help me to come over this. thank you advance

Comment: I think you are doing it the other way round, first what's the relationship between client and `qts`? Next why set things like `Qid` and `Cid` your tables are known and there's always only one primary key field in a table so change it to id, its less confusing that way

Comment: Next, in your models, they are referencing themselves, for example, the qt model `return $this->belongsTo('App\qts'); ` that's not correct as it should reference its parent.

Comment: i changed this still same error i'm getting:-( @depo

Comment: in my project a single client(Cid) can by many items(Qid) so i want to print that which costumer bought what things. Qid means Quote id and Cid means Client ID. @dapo

Comment: i'm getting errror "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'Cid' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `qts` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2019-07-22 11:01:09, 2019-07-22 11:01:09))"

Comment: Please can you show the code you're running that produces this error.

Comment: this is controller   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $qt = Qt::create();
        $qt->Itemname = $request->Itemname;
        $qt->Quantity = $request->Quantity;
        $qt->Price = $request->Price;
        $qt->Tax = $request->Tax;
        $qt->Total = $request->Total;
        $qt->GrandTotal = $request->GrandTotal;
        $qt->Cid = Auth::Cid();
        dd($qt);
        $qt->save();
        return redirect()->route('quotes.show', $request->Cid);
        
   }

Comment: i solved the error before one i was getting that because i have a dropdown select tag in html and its not getting that value what i select. this is my updated code.

Answer (score 1):

A Client `hasMany` qts & a qts `belongsTo` a client. Try to change those relationships first.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Client extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'client';
    protected $primaryKey = 'Cid';
    protected $guarded = ['Qid'];
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'address', 'contact', 'created_at', 'updated_at' ]; 
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\qt',Qid,Cid);
    }
}




class qt extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'qts';
    protected $primaryKey = 'Qid';
    protected $guarded = ['Cid'];
    protected $fillable=['Itemname','Quantity','Price','Tax','Total','GrandTotal','created_at', 'updated_at'];
    public function qts()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client',Cid,Qid);
    }
}
```